# What is this font ? is it customized or what?

Tags: fonts, typography, font-identification

What fonts is this ?? I tried font identification websites but they won't catch it. If anyone have any suggestion about this font, please.

[image]

Comment: The fact that this have a 3D and obviously mostly handrawn, i think it's a drawing of the word and not an actual font. Not sure.

Comment: Googling reveals that it's from a [designer t-shirt](https://www.aninebing.com/collections/t-shirts/products/vintage-bing-tee-black). So the lines are wobbly because it's an image of fabric. Probably straight lines when it lies flat. Anyway, the letters seem to be drawn especially for this word. Imagine what happens if you place the "I" after the "N".

Answer (score 3):

It's drawn.

It is not a "font". It's art.

*None* of the lines are straight.

Comment: I agree that this is most likely not a font, but some of my favourite fonts do not have any straight lines as well. But actually I *do* consider [Zapfino](https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/linotype/zapfino-extra/) more a work of art than a font.

Comment: Zapfino has straight lines.. `:)`